# How can I revert back to the preset incandescent white balance on a Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, white-balance, camera-settings, presets

I have changed the setting on the preset incandescent white balance on my Nikon D5200, and can't seem to find a way to change it back.

Answer (score 3):

In the Incandescent menu, just adjust the dot back to the 0,0 center position of the colored grid.